# how to plot and show the distribution of the dataset in python?

Tags: python, plot, data-visualization, treemap

I have a dataset which a small part of it looks like below,

```
data = [ ['2018-01-01',  1.323 ,    'AI' ,   2000,'Communications','Mothers'], 
   ['2018-01-02',  1.525 ,    'AI',    1500,'Communications','Mothers'],
   ['2018-01-03',  1.045 ,    'AI' ,    500,'Communications','Mothers'],
   ['2018-01-04',  1.845 ,    'AI' ,    600,'Communications','Mothers'],
  ['2018-01-05',  1.045 ,    'AI' ,    500,'Communications','Mothers'],
   ['2018-01-02',  1.446  ,  'BOC' ,    550,'Pharmaceuticals','JASDAQ Standard'],
   ['2018-01-03',  2.110 ,   'BOC' ,   3201,'Pharmaceuticals','JASDAQ Standard'],
   ['2018-01-04',  2.150 ,   'BOC' ,   5200,'Pharmaceuticals','JASDAQ Standard'],
   ['2018-01-05',  2.810 ,   'BOC' ,   1980,'Pharmaceuticals','JASDAQ Standard'],
   ['2018-01-03',  5.199 ,   'CAT' ,   2000,'Real Estate','Mothers'],
  ['2018-01-06',  4.980 ,   'CAT' ,    450,'Real Estate','Mothers'],
  ['2018-01-07',  4.990 ,   'CAT' ,   3000,'Real Estate','Mothers']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns =['date',  'price', 'ticker',  'volume', 'Sector','Market Division'])
```

I want to show which market division has more stock and from which sector.
I tried the treemap as below, but did not work
How can I do this?

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

a=df.groupby(['Market Division','Sector']).count()

a["Exchange"] = "Exchange" # in order to have a single root node
fig = px.treemap(a, path=['Exchange', 'Market Division', 'Sector','ticker'], values='ticker')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try using [stacked plots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html). Here is a dummy example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
labels = list(set([md for md in df['Market Division']]))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
jasdaq = [3434, 5454, 45454] 
mothers = [35345, 64534, 43543]
ax.bar(labels, jasdaq[0], label='Pharmaceuticals')
ax.bar(labels, jasdaq[1], label='Communication')
ax.bar(labels, jasdaq[2], label='Real Estate')
ax.bar(labels, mothers[0], label='Pharmaceuticals')
ax.bar(labels, mothers[1], label='Communication')
ax.bar(labels, mothers[2], label='Real Estate')

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

You need to compute each sector for each Market division first and replace jasdaq and mothers to have the real plot you want.

Comment: thank you @Misgevolution,  I have near hundred of rows , its hard to take all the ticker that belong to specific exchange market manually

Comment: you need to write code for creating a list. The above example is just for demonestration. As long as the plotting style is ok, you should be able to write a code that creates a list of the tickers.